# How to pass a URL parameter using python, Flask, and the command line

Tags: python, http, command-line, flask

I am having a lot of trouble passing a URL parameter using request.args.get.

My code is the following:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/post?id=post_id', methods=["GET"])
def show_post():
    post_id=1232
    return request.args.get('post_id')

if __name__=="__main__":
     app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

After saving, I always type python filename.py in the command line, see Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit) as the return on the command line, and then type in the url (http://ip_addres:5000/post?id=1232) in chrome to see if it will return 1232, but it won't do it! Please help.

Answer (score 12):

You should leave the query parameters out of the route as they aren't part of it.

```
@app.route('/post', methods=['GET'])
def show_post():
    post_id = request.args.get('id')
    return post_id
```

`request.args` is a dictionary containing all of the query parameters passed in the URL.

Comment: What would the URL be then, please? Thank you so much!

Comment: The URL would still be `http://<IP Address>:5000/post?id=1232`.  `id` is a query parameter that will appear in the `request.args` dictionary with the value `1232`. Note I edited the above answer to correct the name of the parameter.

Comment: so basically, the request.args.get('id') automatically inserts the param inside the url?

Comment: No, not at all. You enter the URL `http://127.0.0.1:5000/post?id=1232`. Flask will cut off the query string, which is `?id=1232` and match on the actual path, which is `/post`. That path gets routed to the `show_post` function. `request.args` is a dictionary containing all of the query parameters that were passed along with the URL, which in this case is the key `id` and the value `1232`. `request.args` here will be a dictionary that looks like this: `{"id": "1232"}`.

Comment: @SAS please see my answer also

Answer (score 6):

`request.args` is what you are looking for.

```
@app.route('/post', methods=["GET"])
def show_post()
    post_id = request.args.get('id')
```

request.args is get all the GET parameters and construct `Multidict` like this `MultiDict([('id', '1232'),])` so using `get` you can `get` the id

Comment: Thank you so much! What would the URL be then, please?

Comment: Okay, cool!:D Thank you so much! Your answer was equally helpful! Now I not only can use the code that y'all offered, but also understand what it is doing:)