# How to pass GET parameters to url using Flask Request

Tags: python, flask, request, flask-login, http-request-parameters

I am aware of how to *get* the request parameters from a url using Flask Request: `request.args.get('<param>')`. Indeed, that's the only thing I can find when searching for the title question:

- [How do you get a query string on Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774265/how-do-you-get-a-query-string-on-flask)
- [How to pass a URL parameter using python, Flask, and the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519475/how-to-pass-a-url-parameter-using-python-flask-and-the-command-line)

I need to know how to *send* the request parameter for the user's url.

For example, flask_login has a parameter called "next" that stores the url the user was accessing when they accessed a route wrapped in @login_required so that they can be redirected to it after they log in. I have need of this exact functionality with my own forms but I cannot find a way to do implement it.

The relevant section of the flask-login code is [here](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/7e451269fbb7d58ad2530452a2d3420e0766ce3a/flask_login/login_manager.py#L122), but I cannot understand how they pass the parameter.

I need a way to record the user's url when they click a link to a form page, pass that as a GET request parameter in their url on the form page, and reaccess it when they submit or cancel the form to return them to their previous page.

Comment: use the redirect functionality, or pass it as a query url as http://myserver:myport/mypage?arg1=val1&arg2=val2 etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Per the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.url_for) I have found the answer (@E.Serra for impetus in the right direction):

> `flask.url_for(endpoint, **values)`
>
> Generates a URL to the given endpoint with the method provided.
>
> ***Variable arguments that are unknown to the target endpoint are appended to the generated URL as query arguments.*** If the value of a
>   query argument is None, the whole pair is skipped. In case blueprints
>   are active you can shortcut references to the same blueprint by
>   prefixing the local endpoint with a dot (.).

So if you have the route

```
@app.route('/view/<variable>/')
def view(variable):
    pass
```

The call

```
url_for('view', variable='parameter', variable2='parameter2')
```

will produce a url where parameter2 is a query argument.